Mock Module Variable instead of a callable
If I want to Mock a variable inside a module with the following code:
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_default(mocker, tmp_path):
    """Mock Default Config File Path."""
    mocker.patch("mypackage.mymodule.DEFAULT", return_value=tmp_path / "myfile")

it is returned always as a MagicMock object.
How can I return it as a Path object (or any other type needed)?
What I have noticed while debugging: All methods Path object specific doesn't throw any error. But as example DEFAULT.touch(exsist_ok=True), does not create the file as expected.

Since all Questions and Answers I searched for in the meantime, pointing in the wrong direction, I got it after reading blog post (https://www.helmerdavila.com/blog/en/mocking-global-variables-in-python-tests/) about the topic.
So the described solution wants to replace the return_value by new:
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_default(mocker, tmp_path):
    """Mock Default Config File Path."""
    mocker.patch("mypackage.mymodule.DEFAULT", new=tmp_path / "myfile")

This works in my situtation, but I am not confident, if this is the best solution.
still curious about why the MagicMock doesn't throw any error when calling Path methods!

mocker.patch was replacing the DEFAULT variable with a MagicMock. Unless you declared it with a spec or spec_set, a Mock will feature any attribute you try to access, returning new [Magic]Mocks instances with again free specs. No Mock().nonexistent.method().or.attribute can ever fail by itself, only if the code using that gets upset because of being injected uncrafted mocks. Further reading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing

I am not sure how autospec or spec helps me in this situation, I don't want to Mock the complete Object (which as far as I understand spec and autospec are doing), The new argument instead creates the actual object I need. The docs only describes what happens if I omit new not what happens if I set it.

It won't help you and you shouldn't use that as part of the solution (because you want to replace a module var with a given value but not a mock!). Because you mentioned your were curious about it, this is the explanation on why MagiMock in the first place didn't throw errors when being asked for Path methods. You can use the comment to remove the unknowns from your answer or you can leave that comment as is.

Although I admit I was unclear in my phrasing. My comment made sense in my inner dialogue with a virtual you, sorry. I'll rephrase and repost it unless you include the explanation in the answer. Cheers

Okay I think I understand now what you have described in your first comment. I stumbled about another issue in regards with Global mocking, while the above still works if the module containing the Global it still works, but fails as soon as I import the a function from the module, which uses the Global. In that case the Global is set from the module itself while import and so the mocking is not happening. Am I right?
